# Multiple data attribute filtering with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have run into an issue where i want to filter with multiple data attributes using jquery find.

I have the following dom elements:

```
<span data-selected="no" data-position="y2016m2" data-type="project" data-workplaceid="113" data-languageid="5" data-industryid="3" data-id="pr15" class="month-item dark-text timeline-item project-item"></span>

<span data-selected="no" data-position="y2016m5" data-type="project" data-workplaceid="113" data-languageid="1" data-industryid="5" data-id="pr22" class="month-item dark-text timeline-item project-item"></span>

<span data-selected="no" data-position="y2016m6" data-type="project" data-workplaceid="113" data-languageid="3" data-industryid="3" data-id="pr13" class="month-item dark-text timeline-item project-item"></span>

<span data-selected="no" data-position="y2017m2" data-type="project" data-workplaceid="113" data-languageid="1" data-industryid="1" data-id="pr1" class="month-item dark-text timeline-item project-item"></span>

<span data-selected="no" data-position="y2018m4" data-type="project" data-workplaceid="113" data-languageid="5" data-industryid="2" data-id="pr75" class="month-item dark-text timeline-item project-item"></span>
```

I am trying to use the following negating statement to get rid of all the items that are not needed:

```
$('.timeline').find('.project-item[data-languageid!=5][data-industryid!=3]');
```

The problem with this statement and its behaving as an OR statement and not as an AND statement. So when i run this line of code i get the first element from the list and the third but the third elements data-industryid=3 so it shouldnt be there.

My question is that the double data attribute statement filtering works as an OR statement or as an AND cause how i see here it is working as an OR statement cause on of the id's is the same.

Any advice would be much appreciated.
Thanks
Trix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.not()` or `:not()`

```
$('.timeline').find('.project-item:not([data-languageid=5][data-industryid=3])');
```

Or `.not`

```
$('.timeline').find('.project-item').not('[data-languageid=5][data-industryid=3]');
```

you can also use `:not():not()`

```
 $('.timeline').find('.project-item:not([data-languageid=5]):not([data-industryid=3])');
```

Comment: Good god that solved it! Been at it for a while. Many thanks!

Comment: you're totally welcome @trix87 .. you can use the `:not` selector as you want up to your need as I explained on my answer .. Have a great day :-)

Comment: Will accept the answer in 5 mins. Have a great day!