# jquery filter multiple selections

Tags: jquery, filter

I am working on a filter system for a website whereby products can be filtered to show only those that are selected. I have the following working model:

```
 $(function() {
        var selectedClass = "";
        $(".category").click(function(){ 
        selectedClass = $(this).attr("data-rel"); 
     $(".products").fadeTo(100, 0.1);
        $(".products .all").not("."+selectedClass).fadeOut().removeClass('show');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("."+selectedClass).fadeIn().addClass('show');
      $(".products").fadeTo(300, 1);
    }, 300); 

    });
});
```

Items are filtered using a list and the data-rel selects only those items that have the class assigned to them. This all works fine but I now need the items to be filtered by more than one selection. I want a user to be able to select from one list two options but I only want the options to show that fit both criteria.

For example, if I have items such as 'red' 'green' and 'blue' as well as 'square' 'circle' and 'triangle', I want a user to be able to select 'red' and 'square' and for the results to show only the items that match both of those selections as opposed to all items that match either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See if [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49803344/multiple-data-attribute-filtering-with-jquery) can offer some help. It talks about filtering on multiple data attributes similar to what I think you are looking for.

Comment: That is along the right lines but it's specific in the selections, i need a solution that works without me being specific as i need the user to make the selection of what to add or remove.

Comment: Do you have a sample of your html you can share? Is `. category` a button?

Comment: Sure, for instance the selectors are as follows:

Comment: <li class="nav-item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-6">
          <a class="nav-link category" data-rel="bricks">Bricks</a>
         </li>

Comment: <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 show red bricks all">
 <div class="listing">
  <a href="">
   <img src="" alt="" />
   <div class="content">
    <p>Red Brick</p>
   </div>
   <div class="icons">
    <span class="red"></span>
    <span class="brick"></span>
   </div>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>